# In .Net 1.1 TreeView , 'OnDrawNode' , 'OnNodeMouseClick' , 'OnNodeMouseDoubleClick' and 'TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs' not found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, .net-1.1

In .Net Framework 1.1 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' some virtual methods and one EventArgs not found. they are listed below

1. 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' does not contain a definition for
   'OnDrawNode'
2. 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' does not contain a definition for
   'OnNodeMouseClick'
3. 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' does not contain a definition for
   'OnNodeMouseDoubleClick'
4. The type or namespace name 'TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs' could not
   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
   reference?)

Comment: Whats the actual question? you are correct. if you want these features dont use v 1.1.

Comment: i need to customize the System.Windows.Forms.TreeView' , so that i need above methods and EventsArgs in .Net 1.1. But its available in after .Net 2.0

Comment: Already i done custom treeview  control in .Net 4.0 , but i want to customize in .Net 1.1.                                                 https://github.com/vignesh-nethaji/Windows-Custom-Controls/blob/master/Menporul.Windows/Menporul.Windows.Controls/Menporul.Windows.Controls.csproj

Comment: Here is the source code for [TreeView](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs,babfd7e2e150fae9) in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnDrawNode`,`OnNodeMouseClick`,`OnNodeMouseDoubleClick` events have been introduced in .Net Framework 2.0 and are available since it. 
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode(v=vs.110).aspx)